# using RTSP from wifi connected camera with libstreaming

Tags: android, camera, rtsp, wowza, libstreaming

I am a newbie of using libstreaming.

I am wondering if there is a way to use the libstreaming to pull streaming from established rtsp (internal ip) and use it with libstreaming to send it to WOWZA server.

So, here is my flow.

1)   Connect to camera via Android’s wifi and get rtsp address

2)   Use this rtsp address with libstreaming to send it over to WOWZA server via 4G cellular network.
Found a way of activating WIFI and 4G at the same time within the phone.

But need help to use libstreaming with internally passed rtsp.

Rtsp will have

16:9 aspect ratio with 640x360, bit rate around 1640 kbps.

The stream is running on RTP transport; video part is encoded in H.264 with YUV 4:2:0 pixel format, 30 FPS frame rate.

Main question is if there is a pre-established rtsp connection with the camera via wifi, how do I send it to Wowza using libstreaming (or similar library) via 3g/4g cellular network? I wonder if there is an easy way. Do I need to re-packetize the current stream?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Although this looks interesting what have you found out so far?   This might give us valuable information that will allow all of us to go forward faster

Comment: @Simon      Thank you :)  Example 3 of libStreaming brings the cell phone camera's frame in byte[] form. We also succeeded in importing the camera image frame into the byte[] via wi-fi, but failed to stream that data to the wowza server.

Comment: @Jin did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Is it possible to get to the WOWZA server via WIFI? If not it will require some networking configuration on your android device.
Basically you will need to make some changes to your device routing table so that internet (or only the WOWZA server) will be accessed via cellular network

Answer (score -1):

Check following url/article from WOWZA team that gives you WOWZA-RTSP flow:
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-re-stream-video-from-an-ip-camera-rtsp-rtp-re-streaming

Comment: I am grateful for the answers.
However, the camera I have is not ipcamera.
Even if the mobile phone takes the role of ipcamera as an alternative, I can not refer to this article because the lte network can not be accessed from the outside.